# How to update password information for Netscaler in SoftLayer portal by SoftLayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I executed the following request and got a return value `true`

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller/[ID]/editObject

{"parameters":[{"password":{"password":"[PASSWORD]"}}]}
```

However, it didn't update the password information in SoftLayer Portal. Could I know how to update the password information for netscaler device?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to update the password through API. The password displayed in Portal and API, is the information with which was installed the device.

You need to update the password manually inside the device, follow these steps for it:

> User Administration >> Users >> Select user(e.g: root) >> Change Password